# uiwebview can't go backward

Tags: ios, uiwebview, twitter-feed

I am using one html code snippet to fetch TWITTER FEEDS, code is working fine but once navigating to the twitter feeds I can't go back to the previous page.

I am loading this html content as follow :

```
NSString *twitterFeed = @" <a class=\"twitter-timeline\" href=\"https://twitter.com/search?q=%23diabetes+OR+%23bloodglucose+OR+%23insulin+OR+%23insulinpump+OR+%23type2+OR+%23type1\" data-widget-id=\"386089263655178240\">Tweets about \"#diabetes OR #bloodglucose OR #insulin OR #insulinpump OR #type2 OR #type1\"</a> <script>!function(d,s,id){var js,fjs=d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0],p=/^http:/.test(d.location)?'http':'https';if(!d.getElementById(id)){js=d.createElement(s);js.id=id;js.src=p+\"://platform.twitter.com/widgets.js\";fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js,fjs);}}(document,\"script\",\"twitter-wjs\");</script>";

if (appDelegate.isReachable)
{
    [self.webView loadHTMLString:twitterFeed baseURL:nil];
}
else
{
    UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Alert" message:@"No internet connection !!" delegate:nil cancelButtonTitle:@"Cancel" otherButtonTitles:nil, nil];
    [alert show];
}
```

also I am using following code to go back in webview

```
if ([self.webView canGoBack])
{
    NSLog(@"Can go BACK");
    [self.webView goBack];
}
```

still I am not able to go back. please help me how to do this?

Comment: Do you follow any links within the web view? UIWebView behaves like a normal browser window, but without the buttons and chrome

Comment: yes there is a link as follow :
https://twitter.com/search?q=%23diabetes+OR+%23bloodglucose+OR+%23insulin+OR+%23insulinpump+OR+%23type2+OR+%23type1

Answer (score 0):

The reason go back does not work, is that your twitter widget is loading content via `XMLHTTPRequests`, and thus there is no pages in the history to go back to. I tried clicking a hash-tag, and then the "Install app" button. This created a request which where put in the web views history that I could go back from.

Try loading your web view from an URL like *stackoverflow.com*, and you'll see that your objective-c code works as intended, and that it is the twitter-widget which does not create a browsing history to go back in.

Comment: ya I can go back normally when there is some link like you have suggested above, but how do I solve this problem, have you any solution for this specific issue?

Comment: If you can figure out the correct javascript to trigger the behaviour you need, you could probably solve it by doing ```[self.webView stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:]```